# maven enforcer does not honor rules

Tags: java, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

i am using [maven enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin) version [3.0.0-M3](https://github.com/apache/maven-enforcer/tree/enforcer-3.0.0-M3).

i [configured the rules within the `pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html) as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <mvn.version>3.6.3</mvn.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-versions</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <failFast>true</failFast>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>${mvn.version}</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                <requireJavaVersion>
                  <version>${java.version}</version>
                </requireJavaVersion>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

then i verified the configurations are evaluated correctly:

```sh
$ mvn validate -Djava.version=1.7 -X
...
DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7852e922]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) commandLineRules = []
[DEBUG]   (s) fail = true
[DEBUG]   (s) failFast = true
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreCache = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce {execution: enforce-versions}
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: foo:foo:0.0.1 @ /app/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) version = 3.6.3
[DEBUG]   (s) version = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (s) rules = [org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion@551a20d6, org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion@578524c3]
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@64c2b546
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion
[DEBUG] Rule org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion is cacheable.
[DEBUG] Detected Maven Version: 3.6.3
[DEBUG] Detected Maven Version: 3.6.3 is allowed in the range 3.6.3.
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion
[DEBUG] Rule org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion is cacheable.
[DEBUG] Detected Java String: '1.7'
[DEBUG] Normalized Java String: '1.7'
[DEBUG] Parsed Version: Major: 1 Minor: 7 Incremental: 0 Build: 0 Qualifier: null
[DEBUG] Detected JDK Version: 1.7 is allowed in the range 1.7.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.848 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-02T08:47:43Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but it seems the rules are not honored, since when i run the `enforce`, the `No rules are configured.` error message is shown

```sh
$ mvn enforcer:enforce -Djava.version=1.7
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------< foo:foo >-------------------------------
[INFO] Building foo 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) @ foo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.605 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-02T08:49:54Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) on project foo: No rules are configured. Use the skip flag if you want to disable execution. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

when providing rules through command line argument, it seems the enforcer does evaluate them

```sh
$ mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=alwaysFail
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------< foo:foo >-------------------------------
[INFO] Building foo 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) @ foo ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.AlwaysFail failed with message:
Always fails!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.572 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-02T09:05:57Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) on project foo: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

but setting `<AlwaysFail />` in `/project/build/plugins/plugin/executions/execution/configuration/rules/AlwaysFail` (xpath) doesn't seem to produce the same thing -- keep getting `No rules are configured` when executed without a command line arguments.

i am using maven 3.6.3 and openjdk 1.8 under debian buster

```sh
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_262, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.19.76-linuxkit", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

**UPDATE:**

after moving the `<configuration>` block outside the `<executions>` block and running in a debug mode, i get the output where it shows that the `java.version=0.7` is detected by by the enforcer but it does not fail the build. see below:

```sh
$ mvn validate -Drequired.java.version=0.7 -X
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7852e922]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) commandLineRules = []
[DEBUG]   (s) fail = true
[DEBUG]   (s) failFast = true
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreCache = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce {execution: enforce-versions}
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: foo:foo:0.0.1 @ /app/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) version = 3.6.3
[DEBUG]   (s) version = 0.7
[DEBUG]   (s) rules = [org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion@551a20d6, org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion@578524c3]
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@64c2b546
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion
[DEBUG] Rule org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion is cacheable.
[DEBUG] Detected Maven Version: 3.6.3
[DEBUG] Detected Maven Version: 3.6.3 is allowed in the range 3.6.3.
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion
[DEBUG] Rule org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion is cacheable.
[DEBUG] Detected Java String: '1.8.0_262'
[DEBUG] Normalized Java String: '1.8.0-262'
[DEBUG] Parsed Version: Major: 1 Minor: 8 Incremental: 0 Build: 262 Qualifier: null
[DEBUG] Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-262 is allowed in the range 0.7.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.854 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-02T11:51:19Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

how to make the enforcer fail when the required java and maven version are unmet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after reading reading thoroughly the documentation, specifically [version range specification](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html), when the version is specified as a number, it implies that the version comparison operator is `>=` (greater than or equal to) the version.

to solve the issue, i used square brackets (`[]`), e.g.

```xml
<requireMavenVersion>
  <version>[${mvn.version}]</version>
</requireMavenVersion>
```

as noted, using `java.version` and `mvn.version` are built-in properties.

Answer (score 5):

You configured the rules as part of an `<execution>`.

If you want the configuration to be used also for other executions (like on command line), you need to move the `<configuration>` block outside the `<executions>` block.

It should look like this:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-versions</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
           <failFast>true</failFast>
           <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>${mvn.version}</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                <requireJavaVersion>
                  <version>${required.java.version}</version>
                </requireJavaVersion>
            </rules>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Note that you should not use the property `${java.version}` as it is apparently an "official" property of Maven.

Comment: did as you said but the `requireJavaVersion` still isn't honored while `AlwaysFail` is. could you please shed more light on the issue?

Comment: I have added some xml. Does it help?

Comment: thank you for the edit, i did just that as you explained before the edit. my first comment still holds, the issue persists. specifically, the build succeeds when running `mvn validate -Djava.version=0.7`

Comment: Could you run the build with `-X` to show debug output?

Comment: It may be that your property `java.version` clashes with the "official" property of Maven. So I would rename `${java.version}` to something like `${required.java.version}` and run the build with `mvn validate -Drequired.java.version=0.7`.

Comment: i was quick to accept it. sorry. did the modification but when running with `mvn validate -Drequired.java.version=0.7 -X` the build succeeds and fails with `mvn validate -Djava.version=0.7 -X`

Comment: did it work for you on your lab when using all your suggestion and the same maven and java versions?

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run `mvn validate -Drequired.java.version=0.7 -X`?